# How can I enable 32bit UEFI booting on a Ubuntu installed on a flash drive?

Tags: boot, uefi

Thus far, all the guides I've read either refer to modifying Live ISO to support 32bit UEFI (I've already done this), or running `boot-repair` to fix booting with 64bit UEFI.

Note:  I already managed to boot a Live USB and install the OS to a flash drive.  The problem I have to now is to get the installed flash drive to boot on this device (Z83-W Mini PC with Intel Atom).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using [refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).